# How to match -1 at arbitrary precision?

Tags: pattern-matching

Suppose a want a pattern to match:

```
-1
-1.
-1.`42 (or any other value for the precision)
```

with a pattern. What would be the best pattern to use? I guess one could use

```
_?(N@#==-1.&)
```

but this seems like it shouldn't be the best approach. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think there are significantly better ways to do it, tbh. Is there any reason why you're not satisfied with this pattern? It depends on the application, I guess. If you want to find -1 values in an array, there are vectorised ways to do it.

Comment: `Cases[{-1, -1., -1.\` 42}, _?(# == -1 &)] ` works for me

Comment: `_?(PossibleZeroQ[#+1]&)` perhaps.